# Embedding content in external website

Tags: 7, nodes

I'm new to Drupal (and SE) and am looking for a way to embed Drupal 7 content in an external website.
D6 had modules for that ([web widget](http://drupal.org/project/web_widgets) and [embed widget](http://drupal.org/project/embed_widgets)). 
How can I do it in D7?
Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Web Widgets](http://drupal.org/project/web_widgets) now has a Drupal 7 release, so it might be worth trying it out.

Answer (score 2):

You can implement the `hook_preprocess_page()` in your theme's template.php file to unset the regions you don't need (if your don't do this it will generate a performance issue. see http://www.lullabot.com/articles/drupal-performance-tip-block-visibility) and then you can set a custom template file for the page using the `$variables['theme_hook_suggestions']` variable. This will give you the ability to show just the content region on the desired path on your Drupal site using a custom HTML structure for instance.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_page().
 */
function mytheme_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  $path = request_path();

  if ($path = 'the/path/you/want/to/customize') {
    unset($variables['page']['header']);
    unset($variables['page']['footer']);
    unset($variables['page']['sidebar_right']);
    $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__my_custom_template_file';
  }
}
```

Then you need to create the file page--my-custom-template-file.tpl.php on your theme's templates directory to set the HTML that you need in the page.

```
<div id="custom-content-wrapper">
  <div class="custom-inner-content-div">
    <?php print drupal_render($page['content']); ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

For more info about Drupal theme files, see http://drupal.org/node/171194

After that you will just need to add an iframe tag in the place you need that content on the external website following the example:

```
<iframe src="http://mydrupalsite.com/the/url/to/the/page"></iframe>
```

For more info. about the iframe tag. See http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about a Drupal 7 Module that is out yet. As an interim solution maybe PHP scrapping from your Drupal 7 Installation?

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/html-parsing-and-screen-scraping-with-the-simple-html-dom-library/

The solution is not ideal but might help until one of the projects you posted is ported to 7/

Comment: thank you. Do you think it's possible to create a view and assign a custom template that's more or less blank. Then embed the page with an iframe?

Comment: Web Widgets module does it for you